# Can't uninstall Skype

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, uninstall

I want to uninstall Skype from Ubuntu 12.04. When I run `apt-get remove --purge skype`, Terminal says done.

But when I check `dpkg -l skype`, I get this:

```
>Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================  
un  skype          <none>         (no description available)
```

Answer (score 2):

the output for skype is prefixed by `un` - those two letters are explained in the first two lines.

The first line represents the state the package **should** be in (according to what command you entered last):

```
>Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
```

`u` stands for `Unknown` - which means that dpkg has no info on this package.

The second line represents the actual status.

```
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
```

`n` stands for `Not` - meaning "not installed"

So your `un` means: I don't know `skype` and it is not installed.

in summary:
skype is uninstalled.